# Getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when listening xdebug connections in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I used to debug PHP code locally in PhpStorm using Xdebug but recently it just stopped working. When enabling listening Xdebug connections my PHP application immediately responds with empty response and I see ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Chrome and Firefox. Debugger works though and execution stops on breakpoints as usual. When listening is disabled, application works as expected.

Project is running on local Apache Web Server, but I also explicitly specified path mappings.

How can I "debug" debugger to figure-out what prevents web-server from giving out http response?

xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_port=8888
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/opt/profiler"
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0
xdebug.trace_enable=0
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger=0
xdebug.trace_output_dir="/var/opt/trace"
xdebug.max_nesting_level="1000"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

PhpStorm debugger config:

[image]

Comment: try enabling `xdebug.remote_log=/log_path/xdebug.log` and check the log after a debug session

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this as well with PHP 7.1.27, xdebug 2.7.0. In webserver log on each debug request there was a message "zend_mm_heap corrupted".

The problem has been solved by upgrading to PHP 7.1.28 and xdebug 2.7.1
Based on [this](https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1647) I think the only xDebug upgrade is crucial.

Comment: Thank you.  I was having the same problem, and doing those two upgrades fixed it.

Comment: @BenRubin I am happy it helps! )